# Unable to install create react app on windows 10

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to react and when I run `npx create-react-app my-app` I get the following error message
[image]

I am using 14.5.0 for node and 6.14.8 for npm.

What I have tried so far to resolve the issue:

- Uninstall and reinstall node
- `npm i --no-package-lock`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm cache verify`
- I've tried running it with npm instead of ntx after installing create-react-app but this also fails

Comment: The log seems pretty clear: this is an error with npm itself, please report it at https://npm.community -- having said that, can you explain your actual steps? E.g. you installed Node 14 (which you should update to 14.15 if you're still on 14.5), and then what steps do you take?

Comment: Is there any more info in the log provided? (if there is, add it here and in the linked npm community) - 
The last point that you've tried should have probably handled that but have you installed the package locally and double checked that it is running the local binary and not the globally installed one? And since you're on Windows make sure to run everything as admin just in case you're missing a permission that is a requirement of some obscure dependency.